# How to use the Clojure reader to convert a string in a text file into a function which will resolve

Tags: clojure, datomic

I have a text file of EDN which contains a function to create a SQUUID:

```
[
 {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/people -1001]
  :people.human/uuid (d/squuid)
  ...
]
```

I am reading this file into a var using slurp:

```
(def seed-data (read-string (slurp "path/to/my-edn-file.edn")))
```

When it is read into the var I want the (d/squuid) function to be invoked. I believe this has something to do with the clojure reader, but am stuck on the correct notation to use in the EDN file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`read-string` only reads the forms expressed as `String`. If you want to evaluate them (and you want it to happen as you want the `d/squuid` to be executed) you need to `eval` your form:

```
(def seed-data
  (-> "path/to/my-edn-file.edn"
      (slurp)
      (read-string)
      (eval)))
```

**Security warning**

[`read-string`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read-string) and [`eval`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/eval) might be dangerous as they execute code. You should use them only with data you know is safe (e.g. is not provided from external sources like web forms, external APIs etc.)